# Why is the shape of the orbit of the Earth as it is?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, planets, celestial-mechanics, solar-system

**My View**: I think that if the sun were only force acting on earth (as a centripetal force), the earth would have a circular orbit. Since other planets also exist , there also exists gravitational force between interplanetary bodies. This maybe would cause a elliptical orbit. Is the the right answer to this?

**Specific question:** Since the cycle of revolution is different for different planets , shouldn't there be change in the shape of the orbit of the Earth?

Comment: If there are any changes to be made , it is would be admirable to comment about the changes so they can be made , downvoting a post doesn't certainly help in realizing the problem ..

Comment: You can believe what you want, the solution to the equation of the relative motion for a central potential is (in general) an ellipse not a circle.  The perturbation effect of planets has nothing to do with the eccentricity of the orbits.

Comment: So the orbits of planets are as there is , there is no effect of the planetary forces

Comment: the pertubations are small, difficult to compute (see the wiki article on Urbain Le Verrier and the discovery of Neptune) and do not account for the elliptical orbits.

Comment: Ok thank you..,

Comment: You started out with a wrong "assumption" in your question, which is probably why some people downvoted it. Well I can't change other people's votes. Maybe you should write instead : " _I guess if the sun were only force acting on earth (as a centripetal force), the earth would have a circular orbit. However I'm not sure about that_ ".The main question would still make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Comment: You might want to check Astronomy.SE for a better insight.

Answer (score 3):

In physics one uses mathematics to solve these problems. There are some misunderstandings.

> I believe that if the sun were only force acting on earth (as a centripetal force), the earth would have a circular orbit. Since other planets also exist , there also exists gravitational force between interplanetary bodies. This causes a elliptical orbit.

This is not true. The solution of the orbits for two bodies is exact for the classical gravitational force, and they are the [conic sections.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section)
Bound states are either ellipses or circles.

When more than two bodies  enter the gravitational equation the total solutions are not exact, they have to be numerically calculated . This is successfully done in solar system simulators, for [example here.](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/overview/#otp_real-time,_interactive_solar_system)

They may look like circles, but that is because of the very much larger mass of the sun with respect to the planets.The functions themselves are ellipses

> [What shape describes the orbits of planets in our solar system](https://lisbdnet.com/what-is-the-shape-of-the-orbits-of-the-planets/#What_shape_describes_the_orbits_of_planets_in_our_solar_system)?

> In the 17th century Johannes Kepler showed that planetary orbits are ellipses. Newton’s laws of motion confirmed this. Modelling planetary orbits as ellipses is quite accurate. In fact [NASA](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/310/orbits-and-keplers-laws/) publish the orbital parameters which define the ellipses for the orbits of the planets.

As StrongLizard points out in the comments, the experimental fact that the orbits are elliptical, discovered by Kepler, led to the theory of gravitation by Newton that gives the mathematics . In the mathematics, all objects in the solar system are revolving around the [center of the total mass of the solar system, even the sun.](https://spaceplace.nasa.gov/barycenter/en/) Their revolutions is elliptical because it is the ellipse that fits the data. That's the way they were caught and bound in the solar system ( or evolved into bound masses around their star at the development of galaxies in the cosmological model). –

Comment: I just want to add that, as you wrote "_In the 17th century Johannes Kepler showed that planetary orbits are ellipses. Newton’s laws of motion confirmed this_", in Physics (as far as I know) experiment confirms a theory; so Newton **explained** the Laws given by Kepler. Kepler had already "confirmed it".

Comment: Kepler’s empirical laws went unexplained until the latter half of the
seventeenth century. Newton was fascinated with the problem of
planetary motion and it actually inspired him to formulate his laws of motion and the
law of universal gravitation, which successfully explained Kepler's Empirical Laws of Planetary Motion.

Comment: @anna v , Could u also include in your answer , as to why the orbit is elliptical , is there any reason for such a shape of the orbit ?..

Comment: @AarushiAgarwal this comes out of solving the equation of motion.  There is no “why” as the orbits are not a *specific* specialization of the general solution, which can be found in any number of textbooks.  It would indeed be fantastic if all orbits where the special case of the circular orbit, and one coule rightly ask why Nature selected this specific solution out of the general one.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the orbital motion of the planets, refer to [Kepler's laws](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/keplers-law#:%7E:text=Kepler%27s%20laws%20apply%3A,the%20same%20for%20all%20planets.). For the shape of the trajectory of the planets, it is especially the conservation of angular momentum that interests us:
\begin{equation}
\vec{L} = \vec{r} \times \vec{p}
\end{equation}
This formula implies that the speed of the planets is proportional to the force applied to them, thus their proximity to the sun.

Depending of the force they initially have, trajectories of the planets are **conic sections**:

[image: Conic sections]

As our planets do not have too much kinetic energy, they will describe elliptical trajectories, which are characterized by an eccentricity smaller than 1. The circle has an eccentricity of 0, this is an extreme case which is never observed.

You can learn more about conic sections [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section).

Have a nice Sunday !

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that if the sun were only force acting on earth (as a centripetal force), the earth would have a circular orbit.

Many once thought as you did. I won't go through the full proof that Newton's laws of motion and gravitation imply the orbit is in general an ellipse, but let me give an intuitive reason why a circle isn't right in general.

A circular orbit has only one parameter, its radius. But since Newton's second law mentions acceleration, which is a second-order rate of change, it takes two parameters to describe a path, e.g. the position and velocity at one instant. Effectively, we need two "radii", an ellipse's semi-axes.

This is actually related to another common point of confusion concerning gravity. People often ask why planets don't fall into the Sun the way an object will fall to Earth if you release it. The two-parameter aspect of the path makes the relative directions of velocity and acceleration important, and only the latter is "down". When you drop something, it falls straight if these vectors are parallel; for a circular orbit, they'd have to be perpendicular. In practice, they're something in between, like a ball thrown in an arc.